# Incorrect Syntax When Executing Stored Proc NewId()

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, uniqueidentifier

`IdentityId` is of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type and when I insert a record and set that as `NewId()`, I get the error message

> Incorrect Syntax new )

Not sure what I am missing. Please advice.

Execute command:

```
Exec dbo.CreateUser 
         @Title = 'MR',
         @FirstName = 'John', 
         @LastName = 'Smith', 
         @IdentityId = NewId(), 
         @PhoneNumber = '01234456789', 
         @MobileNumber = '0987654321', 
         @StatesId = 2, 
         @AddressLineOne = '1 A Road',
         @AddressLineTwo = '',
         @Town = 'Some Town',
         @County = 'County',
         @PostCode = 'AA1 1AA',
         @Country = 'United Kingdom',
         @OrganisationName = 'OrgName',
         @OrganisationDomain = 'orgName.com'
```

`CreateUser` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser]
    @Title NVARCHAR(50),
    @FirstName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @LastName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @IdentityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
    @PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(50), 
    @MobileNumber NVARCHAR(50), 
    @StatesId INT, 
    @AddressLineOne NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @AddressLineTwo NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Town NVARCHAR(50),
    @County NVARCHAR(50),
    @PostCode NVARCHAR(10),
    @Country NVARCHAR(20),
    @OrganisationName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @OrganisationDomain NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    INSERT INTO Addresses (AddressLineOne, AddressLineTwo, Town, County, PostCode, Country)
    VALUES (@AddressLineOne, @AddressLineTwo, @Town, @County, @PostCode, @Country)

    INSERT INTO Organisations(Name, Domain, AddressId)
    VALUES (@OrganisationName, @OrganisationDomain, SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    INSERT INTO Users (Title, FirstName, LastName, IdentityId, MobileNumber, PhoneNumber, OrganisationId, StatesId, DateCreated)
    VALUES (@Title, @FirstName, @LastName, @IdentityId, @PhoneNumber, @MobileNumber, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @StatesId, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value to a variable and use that:

```
declare @id uniqueidentifer;

set @id = newid();

exec . . .
     @IdentityId = @id,
     . . .;
```

There is nothing specific about `newid()` here.  The `exec` statement doesn't parse expressions, even simple function calls.

Also, but `begin` and `end` around the stored procedure body.  You should *always* do this, to prevent unexpected errors.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that worked. Can you look at my stored procedure script as it does not let me use Scope_identity to get the ID for the last record

Comment: SCOPE_IDEINTITY() is for IDENTITY columns, no UNIQUEIDENTIFIER columns.  When using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as a key, you should assign them with a DEFAULT, generate them with NEWSEQUENTIALID() and return them with an OUTPUT clause.